# Related Rate of conical tank without height given

Tags: calculus, related-rates

So I am in a calculus 2 class and am stuck on a question as I don't think I have enough information. Can someone please help me with my next step so I can solve this.

> A conical tank is filled at a constant rate of $1 \text{cm}^3/\text{sec}$. How fast does the height increase if the radius is $3$ cm?

Now, I know I'm looking for $\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and I have $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{dt} = 1 \text{cm}^3$, how do I find dh/dt if I don't know the relationship between $h$ and $r$ in the equation $V=\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$?
Can anyone solve it at all? And potentially show the steps?

Comment: Hint: Can you use trigonometry to relate the radius and the height?

Comment: Think of a small bit of water coming in.  It makes a disk that is the area of the top surface of the current water by a small thickness.  You know the area, which is all you need.  You don't care about the overall height.

Comment: But don't I need the height if I need to know how fast the height changes?

Comment: @MorganRose I agree; there isn't enough information. You need some information about the angle of the cone, or something equivalent.

Comment: @TheoBendit why isnt $dh/dV=3/(\pi r^2)$ so $dh/dt=(3/(\pi r^2)dV/dt$?

Comment: @TheoBendit   then plug in $r=3$ and $dV/dt=1$? is this wrong?

Comment: @user140776 Because finding dV/ dt requires product rule.  With implicit differentiation   $dV/ dt = pi /3  (2r h dr/dt +  r^2 dh/dt)$
Not the more intuitive but incorrect,   $dV/ dt = pi (2r h ) /3  $

Comment: @nickalh i see that now. it doesnt make sense physically to assume r is constant, because then the shape of the tank has to be variable

Comment: Is that the entirety of the exercise?  Is this part of a larger exercise?  Maybe first part implies another relationship?  
My take so far- h itself might not be required,but I think we do need more information  Often, angle of the cone is sufficient.   For example at 45 degrees, height = radius, h = r, then we can substitute and simplify down to fewer variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta$ denote the semi-angle of the cone. Then $r = h \tan \theta$. Hence, the volume of the cone can be written as $V = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h = \frac{1}{3} \pi h^3 \tan^2\theta$. The important thing to note here is that $\theta$ does not change with time. Upon differentiating the expression of volume with respect to $t$, we have,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = \pi h^2 \tan^2 \theta \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}t} = \pi r^2 \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}t} $$
So when $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = 1 \text{cm}^3/\text{sec}$  and the radius is $3$ cm, $\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{9\pi}$ cm/sec.

Note that this is also what someone pointed out in their comments. When the radius is $r$, the instantaneous increase in volume is the volume of the cylinder with radius $r$ and height $\mathrm{d}h$, i.e., $ \mathrm{d}V = \pi r^2 \mathrm{d}h$, which is exactly what we obtained in the above solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Every example I have done has extra bits of information so even after you commented about bringing in trig I was unsure how that would assist me. Thank you for explaining. You have saved me an incredible amount of time and confusion.

Comment: Now that's a neat trick.  Convert volume to be dependent on $h^3$ and constants.  The derivative becomes $k h^2 \cdot tan^2 \theta \cdot \frac{dh}{dt}$.  Because the degrees for h and tan are now the same we can replace all h's and $\theta$ putting r back in.